# internal transfer : when do i ask for a raise?

Tags: salary, new-job, france, belgium

I currently work as a lab technician, junior level, in Belgium (French company)

I asked for a new job in the same company (same building, different team). The new job is to lead a small team (starting with 3, expected to grow to 5-6 people) In charge of building prototypes, so that includes dealing with designers, suppliers, plannings, etc.

This position had been open for 6 month before I applied, and they found nobody.

My application has been accepted, and according to oral (unofficial & non definitive) communication, I should be starting my new job 2 month from now (mid september).

During the interview process, I mentioned the fact that i expected a salary raise (since my level of responsibility will increase significantly), and the HR representative agreed, but said that she was not the right person to talk about that. I do not know if this is recorded somewhere in her report, and there has been no mention of a new contract.

This HR rep. left the company two weeks ago, and I have been left without any real news since then, and i do not know who is in charge of my case in HR.

We are in the middle of the summer vacations, which means that my current manager and my future manager are both away.

I fear that if I wait until the end of summer, i will start working my new job, and if I ask for a raise at that time, negociations will be rushed, or I will be told that I should have asked earlier.

How do I approach this? should i go to *someone* in HR or just wait and see?

Comment: Have you signed a contract for the new position yet?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere She did not mention anyone

Answer (score 7):

I see how this has turned into a tricky situation. Essentially, it's your politeness (in not wanting to push the issue) that has backed you into somewhat of a corner.

I'd go and see someone in HR (seeing as it's normally them that would handle salaries/contracts). If it were me the conversation would start like;

> I'm currently a Junior Lab Technician, but I'm due to start a new role as a Team Leader at the start of September (*for example*).
>
> I'm a little worried as I still haven't confirmed my new salary with anyone - I think there's probably been a mix up since *HR Person* left a couple of weeks ago.
>
> Could we please get this sorted as soon as possible, as I don't want it to delay my start date.

A promotion like yours should come with an increase in salary. Until you're explicitly told otherwise - I'd take the approach that *you are getting one*. I'd also raise the issue that you wouldn't want to start your new role before finalising the details of your employment.

You should have all this in your new contract though...

Comment: Well sad thing is there was no mention of a new contract

Comment: @Sclrx you're going to be employed in a new role - you should absolutely have a new contract as your current one will, or at least should anyway, state your current job role. Your new role could have different terms (holiday, perks, notice period) so should be a new contract.

Answer (score 1):

I'd push for getting the raise and change in job title and/or responsibilities with an official start date **in writing before starting the new job** (e.g. "I don't feel comfortable starting in this new position until we've discussed and agreed upon the salary and how exactly my responsibilities would change").

Once you start the job, it's implied that you accept doing that job for your current salary, so that doesn't put you in a particularly good negotiating position and it might be seen as trying to take advantage of the situation (in that they already went through the process of changing your job, then you ask for more money since them just paying that might be less trouble than them reverting you back to your old position and finding someone else).

Whether you go and speak to "someone in HR" to try to push for this now (while the relevant managers are on leave) or wait until they're back (if there's some time between them coming back and you needing to start) would need to be your decision, but keep in mind that:

- Your raise doesn't *need* to take more than a few days to get approved (but this could depend on your company, and, more importantly, it can get significantly delayed at any given point if there isn't sufficient motivation to get it pushed through).
- This raise might need to get approved by either or both managers.
- The start date may not be fixed. The fact that it was only given verbally heavily supports this. I would suggest treating the start date as entirely flexible and gently but firmly insist on pushing out the start date until you agree on the new salary if you're having trouble making that conversation happen.

Answer (score 1):

Promotions are usually accompanied by some sort of a raise that is usually somewhere between 5 -8% so I would say you are being very fair in thinking you should get one. Speak/meet with the manager of the person who extended you the offer ( I assume someone in HR) and explain your reasoning for it as well. Maybe give your accomplishments in written, your goals for what you hope to accomplish etc., as a valid argument for your side. Good Luck